# How do I get an output of lines that comes as a result merging lines in 2 files line by line, then save the output in a third file? (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

I have to take lines from 2 files, put them side by side and write them into a new text file.

File 1 "pythonStatements.txt":

```
    enter code hereprint("Hello World")       # print statement

   x = x + 1      #Assignment statement 

  for i in range(1,n):    #for loop with range  

         calculateSum(a,b)   #function call
```

File 2 "machineCode.txt":

```
0000000000010100

1100110011001100

1010101010101010

1001001001001000
```

Write code that combines the 2 files line by line and the output should be in a new file.

My code:

```
mct = open("machineCode.txt", "r")
pst = open("pythonStatements.txt", "r")

for linex in pst:
    linex=linex.lstrip()
    linex=linex.rstrip()
    for liney in mct:
        x=open("NewFile","w")
        x.write("%s %s \n"%(linex,liney))
```

I am able to put the first lines of the 2 files side by side, and save the output in a third file, but the other lines are not showing for some reason. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and what i can do to fix it?

Output in the third file should look like this:

```
print("Hello World")       # print statement 1001001001001000 

x = x + 1      #Assignment statement 1001001001001000 

for i in range(1,n):    #for loop with range 1001001001001000 

calculateSum(a,b)   #function call 1001001001001000
```

NEW CODE:

```
mct = open("machineCode.txt", "r")
pst = open("pythonStatements.txt", "r")
x=open("output.txt","w")
​
for linex in pst:
    for liney in mct:
        print("")
    x.write("%s %s \n"%(linex.lstrip().rstrip(),liney))
​
mct.close()
pst.close()
x.close()
```

Ouput of the NEW CODE:

```
print("Hello World")       # print statement 1001001001001000 
x = x + 1      #Assignment statement 1001001001001000 
for i in range(1,n):    #for loop with range 1001001001001000 
calculateSum(a,b)   #function call 1001001001001000
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
print("Hello World")     0000000000010100
x = x + 1    1100110011001100
for i in range(1,n):     1010101010101010
calculateSum(a,b)    1001001001001000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you open file for rewriting every iteration in the loop.

```
with open("machineCode.txt") as mct:
    with open("pythonStatements.txt") as pst:
        with open("NewFile", "w") as new:
            for line_x, line_y in zip(mct, pst):
                new.write(line_x.strip() + line_y)
```

---

```
mct = open("machineCode.txt")
pst = open("pythonStatements.txt")
new = open("NewFile", "w")

while True:
    try:
        new.write(next(mct).strip() + next(pst))
    except StopIteration:
        break
        
mct.close()
pst.close()
new.close()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I have 2 questions. Is there a way to do this without zip? Could you explain to me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Also, Is there a way to do what this without with statements or zip? Basically doing it like i did but something that actually works. I just started learning file editing so this is all new to me.

Comment: @Budgie At quick glance there are two problems: rewriting the new file in the loop because you every time open it again & write from scratch, using nested loop so you iterate the whole second file for the first line of the first file and after that you stop at the end. By the way, you do not close files. Either do this in the end or use `with` as it does this automatically. So `zip` is necessary for paralleling reading of lines from both files.

Comment: What you said here, "nested loop so you iterate the whole second file for the first line of the first file and after that you stop at the end", any suggestions on what i can do to make it so that it doesn't only loop over the 1st line of the 1st file using my method? I made this edit:                                     
mct = open("machineCode.txt", "r")
pst = open("pythonStatements.txt", "r")
x=open("NewFiles","w")

for linex in pst:
    linex=linex.lstrip()
    linex=linex.rstrip()
    for liney in mct:
        x.write("%s %s \n"%(linex,liney))
mct.close()
pst.close()

Comment: @Budgie Umm… I mentioned the function `zip` above. It iterates through several iterable objects (files in our case) as arguments. Every time it gives a tuple of elements: one from each sequence. If we specify a number of variables after `for` equal to the length of tuple (so the number of iterable objects), every element is connected to an appropriate variable.

Comment: @Budgie I do not see your new code wholly but your correction sounds right.

Comment: IDK how to put format in the new code properly in the comments of stackoverflow. So i put the new code at the end of the original post. Unfortunately, the new code outputs only the last line of the 2nd file but it properly outputs all the contents of the first file. If you could take a look at the new code in the original post above and give me some feedback, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Budgie As it was aforementioned by me, you iterates through the second file completely & write only the last line in `write`. If you put `write` into `for liney in mct:` loop, you will get 4 combinations the first line of the first file with the second file ones. So your sole solution is using joint iteration – `zip`-function. Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it without zip that's all. But thanks a lot for helping me understand.

Comment: @Budgie [The link](https://pythontutor.com/) where you can scrutinise all the processes inside your code.

Comment: @Budgie `next` method. I see You're a man of culture as well :)

Comment: hey thanks for the link, looking at it right now. Could you tell me how i can mark a comment or your post as right? This is my first ever post on stack overflow. So i have no clue what button does what.